# In a regular MVC view table, rendering more than a few Blazor components triggers a disconnect from the server

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In a .NET Core 3.1 MVC application, we use blazor components to for creating and editing records in a table.

The table is built in a CSHTML view, and the rows are supplied by foreaching through a list.

Each row has one 'edit' button, which is actually a blazor component set to 'prerender', and which takes in the record as a parameter.

When the view loads, some 500+ records are added to the table, and each record gets one instance of the component. We didn't expect very good performance out of it, but appereantly after around 70 rows are added to the table, the blazor server sends a disconnect signal to the client - the reason for which I have not yet discovered - and I'm guessing that somewhere a limit is reached.

We know there is no exception happening in the blazor component itself, because **the same behavior can be reproduced when you use a component that has just a simple paragraph tag with text.**

Some solutions we've come up with are:

- Moving the whole table to a blazor component, since we've built pure blazor apps that never have had this issue. But this comes at a downside because, that would mean we need to manually do the JS stuff and manage the table instantiation ourselves. This is not an option.
- Using the RenderTreeBuilder API to use 1 instance of the EditModalComponent, and manually build the component when it's necessary. But so far, I haven't been able to output the actual component, just the namespace. This still seems like it would be a best-of-both-worlds situation, where I can keep the number of rendered components to 1 (instead of 500). This would be my bet.

I'm about to open a question on using the RenderTreeBuilder in this particular case, but I'm wondering whether **anyone can explain to me, why below solution will trigger a disconnect after a certain number of components?** Am I overloading the SignalR connection?

```cs
<!-- Table implements Datatables.js -->
<table id="table" class="table hover responsive row-border" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var record in Model.Records) // Count would be around 500 records.
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@record.FullName</td>
                <td><component type="typeof(EditModalComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-Record="@record" /></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The *real* solution is to just not put 500 rows into a table that nobody is ever going to view. Use virtual scrolling to pull from the server *only* the data that's needed and display it. Server-size Blazor makes this *a lot* easier than it was with server-side MVC only

Comment: Displaying 500 input boxes in a single page isn't going to make the *browser* happy either. People tried to do that in the past but HTML rendering slowed down to a crawl. That's why you never see long tables of input boxes. Instead, *all* grids* display a different edit template when a user clicks on a cell or row. Even in `in-place` edit mode, edit controls only appear when a user edits or tabs or moves to a cell

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion. Unfortunately, as we have a requirement to use datatables.js, rewriting the table to be a Blazor component is not the way I want to go because this increases complexity by having to manage JS from the blazor component. The real issue here isn't even the 500 records, although this could indeed be optimized. Rendering more than just a handful components on the page will ultimately still cause a disconnect from the server.

Comment: You misunderstood what I wrote then. In any case, you haven't posted your code, so you're asking people to guess why those components are so heavy. Blazor Server produces Javascript and updates the DOM with events sent from the server. It's *not* a Web Component technology. What does your component do that causes such a high traffic? What does the DOM look like? What does the browser's console show? The Network tab?

Comment: In addition to that, the components don't really output any HTML, they're just a marker. And only after the button is clicked signalling the component needs to turn visible, all it does is output that button. Nothing else.

Comment: In short, the component does something weird but people have to guess what that is. The question can't be answered like this

Comment: Sorry, but in my question I clearly state that 'the same behavior can be reproduced when you use a component that has just a simple paragraph tag with text.'. So it does not matter how bloated the component may or may not be.

Comment: Post [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem. Don't ask people to create a project from scratch and try to make it fail just to reproduce the issue. And again, where is the debugging information? What does the **console log show**? If there's a disconnect, it will appear in the browser's console.

Comment: Instead of having a component for each row, would it better to put the whole table inside the component?

Comment: **Please read the whole question before giving suggestions. As much as I appreciate your suggestions, there is no point in suggesting something that is not an option due to business requirements.** @PanagiotisKanavos I hear you, and I'll get you that minimal reproducable example. In case you don't want to wait, just create a new MVC app with .NET Core 3.1, include blazor server, create a stupidly simple component with no logic, and see what happens if you add 30+ of them to a view from a loop. This will be my minimum reproducable example..